# Request Bitbucket API with an access token

Tags: python, authentication, bitbucket

I'm trying to call `Bitbucket API` in my python script to retrieve some data.
I use the `key/secret` pair of `Bitbucket OAuth`.

```
data = { 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
response = requests.post('https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token', data=data, auth=(key, secret))
print(response.json())
access_token = response.json()['access_token']
print(access_token)
groups = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/myaccount/", headers={"Bearer %s" %access_token})
print(groups.json())
```

This gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vagrant/projects/tools/axb-dsi-api/app/bitbucket_connector.py", line 35, in get_groups
    groups = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/myaccount/", headers={"Bearer %s" %access_token})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 306, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 438, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How do we use access token to call BitBucket API REST ?

**EDIT**
After correcting the header to json :

now it's saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/vagrant/projects/tools/axb-dsi-api/app/bitbucket_connector.py", line 36, in get_groups
    print(groups.json())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfuly get to retreive the data from Bitbucket API by passing the access token this way:

```
groups = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/myaccount/access_token={%s}"%access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

the headers parameter to the requests.get() should be an dictionary and you are sending set instead of the dictionary check your code it is `headers={"Bearer %s" %access_token}` which treated as set you can execute this on python and check.

You may need to use key:value check below example:

```
groups = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/myaccount/", headers={'access_token' : "Bearer %s" %access_token})
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I get another error

Comment: please check if you are getting any response in `groups`

Comment: Yes I get to print the access token, but can't print the json of the second request

Comment: I think you are not getting any response for second request i.e. `groups`

Comment: That's strange. I can get a response when I use my username password for authentication but not when I use an access token

Answer (score 0):

Use `Authorization` as a key in the header instead of `access_token` try below code.

```
groups = requests.get("https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/groups/myaccount/", headers={'Authorization' : "Bearer %s" %access_token})
```